# Inject depedency if defined?

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular module called gMap. It  outputs google maps.
I also have module called Current Position. It gets the current location from the browser location api and broadcasts it when/if the user approves the location.

I would like to allow my gMap module to listen for the broadcast of currentLocation, but I would not like currentLocation to be a requirement in using gMap. If I do this:

```
angular.module('gMap', ['currentLocation']).
```

Current location must be defined. Is it possible to broadcast to a module without injecting or use something like "isset" to inject dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the $injector service to see if a service is available.

For example, in some of your gMap's startup code, you can do:

```
 if( $injector.has('currentLocation') ) {
      // setup your broadcast listener
 }
```

See [$injector docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/%24injector)